# "Failed to pull image: pull access denied" on a private docker repository

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run my node application (which successfully runs on my PC with Docker Desktop) through Kubernetes. This is a raspberry pi multi-node ubuntu kubeadm server (everything is latest stable version). I do have successful pods running on this server. I followed [Kubernetes official guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line) to login to my private docker repository on Docker hub. I have double checked my credentials and I can use docker without `sudo` privileges.

My exact setup is listed below, please comment if you want me to add any more information!

My error code:

> Failed to pull image "matthewvine/node-tools:rewrite": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for matthewvine/node-tools, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

My `regcred` docker secret:

```
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: ey...==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-10T23:34:40Z"
  name: regcred
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1807979"
  uid: 69...
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

My `node-ht` deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: node-ht
  namespace: node
  ...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-ht
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: node-ht
          image: matthewvine/node-tools:rewrite
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              protocol: TCP
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
```

**My Soluton**: Turns out it was a simple namespace issue. Secrets need to be in the same namespace as the resources trying to use them.

Comment: Just to clarify, isn't missing `apiVersion` in the `regcred`? Even though I dont think it is the error...

Comment: Did you push the image to the registry? Does the image exist for the platform you are attempting to run it on (the Pi is going to be an ARM variant)? If the answer is yes, then either the name is wrong, or the credentials are wrong and I'm not sure how we'd debug that for you.

Comment: @pedro_bb7 that's not the issue, I just used describe and it doesn't list the full y'all structure.

Comment: @BMitch I guess I hadn't thought about your first 2 questions as I was able to run `docker pull` and successfully pull the container. I'm not sure how I can check for this, but I assume that it's a yes since `docker pull` was successful. Also, like I mentioned the name and credentials have been double checked. Any thought on more debugging or logging that I can do to dig deeper into this issue?

Comment: If you run a pod (not on the host) and try to nslookup for `matthewvine`, does it resolve to the IP address that your private registry is running on?

Comment: Your cited `Secret` is in NS `default`, and your cited `Deployment` is in NS `node`; is that copy pasta or the actual problem?

Comment: @mdaniel This was the problem as the answer below provided more detail into. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secret key must be in the **same place** as the app **namespace**.

If you want to connect your docker secret to kubernetes you can use below method.

**Create a Secret based on existing Docker credentials** ([link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials))

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

I think you already did that. The namespace change should fix your problem

Comment: This solved my issue, I had already created the secret but it was in a different namespace. Thanks!